# OnePlus 3: Unknown process 99041

Tags: applications, oneplus-3

I seem to have this odd app 99041 running in the background and I have no idea what it is. The fact that it doesn't even have a proper name makes me think it's a bit dodgy.

Any ideas?

[image: OnePlus][image]

Comment: I did do some searching before I posted this; I don't have an issue with battery usage as that process used up a mere 1%. My question was about the process itself and what it does, as I've never seen it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it has no name but just "a number", it's usually some "native" system background process (the number is the "user ID"). You could find out more using `adb shell` or a terminal app, if you're not afraid of the command line – or using a process [monitor app](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_systeminfo). A good choice here would be *OS Monitor,* which is available [on F-Droid](https://f-droid.org/repository/browse/?fdid=com.eolwral.osmonitor) as well as [on Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor):

[image: OS Monitor] [image: OS Monitor]
<sup>*OS Monitor* (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eolwral.osmonitor); click images for larger variants)</sup>

Your candidate would find its equivalent in the process "149" (3rd line from the bottom) in the first screenshot. Being a "native binary", Android cannot find any information in its package list, and thus only gives an ID. First entry in the second screenshot shows what details you can additionally obtain on a process by using *OS Monitor.*